# microsoft edge and nightwatch

Tags: selenium, microsoft-edge, nightwatch.js

for some reason, I have not been able to get tests working in Microsoft Edge Windows 10.

Here's my nightwatch config

```
"edge": {
            "use_ssl": false,
            "silent": true,
            "output": true,
            "desiredCapabilities": {
                "browserName": "MicrosoftEdge",
                "platform": "Windows 10",
                "version": "13.10586",
                "screenResolution": "1280x1024",
                "avoidProxy": true
            }
}
```

Has anyone been able to get their tests working in Microsoft Edge? 
If so, what version of selenium do you use? I use 2.52
What version of the edge driver do you use?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need Microsoft Edge Webdriver. You may download it from here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/

Then in nigthwatch.js config you need to specify path to you edge webdriver (`webdriver.edge.driver` arg). This is how my config looks like:

    `"selenium": {
        "start_process": true,
        "server_path": "./node_modules/file_dependencies/selenium-server-standalone.jar",
        "log_path": "",
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "port": seleniumPort,
        "cli_args": {
            "webdriver.chrome.driver": "./node_modules/file_dependencies/chromedriver.exe",
            "webdriver.ie.driver": "./node_modules/file_dependencies/IEDriverServer.exe",
            "webdriver.edge.driver": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Web Driver/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe",
            "webdriver.gecko.driver": "./node_modules/file_dependencies/geckodriver.exe",
            "webdriver.firefox.profile": ""
        }
}`

Rest of your config looks fine

Answer (score 1):

I had issues getting edge to work using Selenium 3.9.1 where Selenium was attempting to use the geckodriver to run tests against Edge.

My configuration looked as follows (snippet to keep to the point):

```
"selenium" : {
    "cli_args" : {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "bin\\chromedriver.exe",
      "webdriver.edge.driver" : "bin\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe",
      "webdriver.gecko.driver" : "bin\\geckodriver.exe",
      "webdriver.firefox.profile": ""
    }
},

"test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "edge",
        "marionette": true
        }   
    }
}
```

I was able to get around this by changing "edge" to "ie" and the browser name to "internet explorer" - see the updated configuration:

```
"selenium" : {
    "cli_args" : {
        "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "bin\\chromedriver.exe",
        "webdriver.ie.driver" : "bin\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe",
        "webdriver.gecko.driver" : "bin\\geckodriver.exe",
        "webdriver.firefox.profile": ""
    }
},

"test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
        "launch_url" : "http://localhost",
        "selenium_port"  : 4444,
        "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
        "silent": true,
        "screenshots" : {
            "enabled" : false,
            "path" : ""
        },
        "desiredCapabilities": {
            "browserName": "internet explorer",
            "marionette": true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The auto-generated `nightwatch.conf.js` already includes configuration for Edge browser, so you can just run by flagging the `edge` environment:

```
nightwatch --env edge
```